# Can't send two events from the same cubit

Tags: flutter, events, bloc

I've faced an issue using Cubit pattern: I have two streams listening to updates and I emit new events each time I receive a new notification, but I can only handle the first event and not the second. I know that each state need to be unique for Equatable to work properly so I used super(props) but it still does not work. I even tried to set the props to randomly generated values and it's still the sale. These are my events:

```
part of 'counters_cubit.dart';

abstract class CountersState extends Equatable {
  final List myProps;
  CountersState(this.myProps);
  @override
  List<Object> get props => myProps;
}

class CountersInitial extends CountersState {
  final Counter counter;
  CountersInitial(this.counter) : super([counter]);
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [counter];
}

class CounterStoreState extends CountersState {
  final Counter counter;
  CounterStoreState(this.counter) : super([counter]);
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [counter];

  bool isANotificationUnread() {
    return counter.nbUnreadChats != 0 ||
        counter.nbNewMatches != 0 ||
        counter.nbNewViews != 0 ||
        counter.nbNewLikes != 0;
  }
}

class NewLikesState extends CountersState {
  final List<User> likes;
  NewLikesState(this.likes) : super([likes]);
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [likes];
}

class NewViewsState extends CountersState {
  final List<User> views;
  NewViewsState(this.views) : super([views]);
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [views];
}
```

This is my states emitting:

```
viewsStream.listen((views) async {
      int nbViews = views.length;
      int nbNewViews = views.where((view) => !view.isViewed).length;

      _database.put(nbViews: nbViews);
      _database.put(nbNewViews: nbNewViews);

      final ids = views.map((e) => e.id).toList();
      final users = await UsersFromIDsFetcher().fetch(ids);
      users.forEach((e) => MemoryStore().putUser(e));

      emit(NewViewsState(users));
    });

    likesStream.listen((likes) async {
      int nbLikes = likes.length;
      int nbNewLikes = _previousLikes == null
          ? nbLikes
          : likes.where((like) => !_previousLikes.contains(like)).length;

      _database.put(nbLikes: nbLikes);
      _database.put(nbNewLikes: nbNewLikes);

      final users = await UsersFromIDsFetcher().fetch(likes);
      users.forEach((e) => MemoryStore().putUser(e));

      emit(NewLikesState(users));
    });
```

Comment: Have you made sure that the values that you're passing are immutable? And aren't changing within the state as you update the values?

Comment: thanks for your answer! I resolved the issue by changing the BlocBuilder which was waiting for the event by a BlocListener